# Javascript syntax for Base64Utils.decode() java code

Tags: javascript, java, base64, decoding, cryptojs

I have an encryption and decryption method in Java. I want to create same decryption function in JavaScript. I am translating line by line, but have an issue in one line as I am not able to understand that. That line is:

```java
byte[] dec = Base64Utils.decode(encryptedString.getBytes());
```

How can I do this in JavaScript. I know .getBytes can be replicated by using text encoder, but I'm not sure about base64 decoding it.

For reference, here is the Java method I am trying to replicate

```java
public String decrypti(String encryptedString, String encodekey) {
    try {
        if (encryptedString != null) {
            encryptedString = encryptedString.replace("-", "+").replace("_", "/").concat("==");

            Cipher dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            byte[] key = encodekey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            key = sha.digest(key);
            key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16); // use only first 128 bit

            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, transformation);

            dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
            // decode with base64 to get bytes
            byte[] dec = Base64Utils.decode(encryptedString.getBytes());
            byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(dec);

            // create new string based on the specified charset
            return new String(utf8, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error during decrypting code - {}", e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

And here is the JavaScript code that I have written till now:

```js
const decrypt = (encodedString, encodeKey) => {
  let encrptedStr = encodedString.replace(/-/g, "_").replace(/\+/g, "/").concat("==");
  
  const encoder = new TextEncoder('UTF-8');
  const bytes = encoder.encode(encodeKey);  // reference to encodekey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
  const sha1Hash = CryptoJS.SHA1(bytes);                        // Create SHA1 hash
  const secretAesKey = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(sha1Hash.words.slice(0, 4)); 

  const decryptedBytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
    encrptedStr,
    secretAesKey,
  );
  const finalDecryptedValue = decryptedBytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
  return finalDecryptedValue;
}
```

Comment: Base64 is a way to take binary data and encode it in human readable ASCII. Take three 8 bit values, and output four base64 values. To decode you do the reverse. There are 3 distinct Base64 alphabets, so you'll need to find the correct one.

Comment: I don't normally do JavaScript, but wouldn't the equivalent be `atob(encryptedString)`?

Comment: atob is now depricated, and I foud way to decode Uint8Arrays to string (base64 conversion). But I am looking for a way to decode Uint8array to decode into Uint8array (not to string). I am confused in this part as the Java function Base64Utils.decode() is taking byte array and returning bytearray again

Comment: *I am confused in this part as the Java function Base64Utils.decode() is taking byte array and returning bytearray again* Because base64 usually encodes binary data, which can't be used to create a string